# Are there Firefox extension (or any other browser) that allow to send arbitrary POST data to a webpage?

Tags: firefox, http-post

I want to test the security of a website of mine and I would love to have an application that is able to send POST data, **if** it's even possible..

Thanks

Comment: Not a programming question. Belongs on superuser.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, Should all testing questions be asked on superuser? Testing is akin to programming - IMHO.

Comment: @doobie: *penetration testing* questions? Ehrm, yes ... likely even on one of the more tailored SE sites, rather than SuperUser or ServerFault. Perhaps Webmasters or IT Security ... but not here. I'm afraid I still disagree with leaving this on SO, even if no one did agree back then and moved the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there are two I know of:

- [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data-for-ff-quantum/) ([Github](https://github.com/Pamblam/Tamper-Data-for-FF-Quantum))
- [<s>Modify Headers</s>](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/967)

Comment: Both the links are dead now.

Answer (score 15):

Try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). From their own documentation:

"The Request Builder allows you to craft custom requests to send to the server.  You can either create a new request manually, or you can drag and drop a session from the Web Sessions list to create a new request based on the existing request."

[image]
<sub>(source: [ifinity.com.au](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Portals/0/images/fiddler-request-detail.JPG))</sub>

Comment: +1 for including a snippet of documentation and a screenshot.

Comment: from the fiddler website -   System Requirements: Windows 2K / XP / 2K3 / Vista / 2K8 / Win7 Microsoft .NET Framework v2.0 or later 8 megabytes disk space / 800mhz processor (Screams at 2.4ghz) 256 megabytes RAM (1GB+ highly recommended)

Comment: This is not a firefox plugin

Comment: It is not a plugin indeed, it's a standalone app. But it provides much reacher functionality and works really well.

Answer (score 8):

- [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/restclient/) : request oriented and user-firendly (runs in a tab, XML answer coloration)

  Development version (works with Firefox 4.b9) here :

  https: //github.com/chao/RESTClient
- Poster : handling binary data POST (with file loading)

  https: //addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/poster/

Comment: +1 Convenient, friendly UI on this Firefox add-in

Comment: RESTClient works really well for RESTful requests!

Answer (score 6):

A fire fox add on named [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) dose exactly that.

Answer (score 5):

I think [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will allow this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe LiveHTTPHeaders can do this (http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/).

But you need to first capture an actual GET/POST request, then click "Replay...".  There, you can edit your request (including the headers) as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Resource Test](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-resource-test) worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

HttpRequester.. Just Awesonme...