# How do I do a POST request on Amazon cloudfront API

Tags: api, amazon-cloudfront

How do I do a POST control request to the Amazon cloudfront API? In the docs it says:

```
Send a CloudFront control API request that is similar to the following example.

POST /2012-05-05/origin-access-identity/cloudfront HTTP/1.1
[Required headers]  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-05-05/">
  <CallerReference>20120229090000</CallerReference>   
  <Comment>Your comments here</Comment>
</CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig>
```

I looked around for some information, and I am not sure how to do it. Is it something I can do via a Curl Request like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php)?

Any help very appreciated! I feel a little lost at the moment.

Many thanks!

***Update***

I do something like this now, still not working.. Any help?

```
<?php
$xml = 'POST /2012-05-05/origin-access-identity/cloudfront HTTP/1.1
Host: cloudfront.amazonaws.com
Authorization: [AWS authentication string]
Date: [time stamp]
[Other required headers]    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-05-05/">
   <CallerReference>ref</CallerReference>
   <Comment>The comment.</Comment>
</CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig>
';

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>'POST',
        'header'=>"Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" .
            $auth."\r\n",
        'content'=>$xml
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = 'https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2012-05-05/origin-access-identity/cloudfront';
$fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
$response = stream_get_contents($fp);
print_r($response);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: What do you want to know ?
The example you are trying is for creating Origin Access Identity via Post Request. So first clarify what do you want ? and what problem are you facing ? **Creating Distribution**
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/2012-05-05/APIReference/CreateDistribution.html **Creating Origin Access Identity.**
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/2012-05-05/APIReference/CreateOAI.html

Comment: It says: "To create a new CloudFront origin access identity, you do a POST on the 2012-05-05/origin-access-identity/cloudfront resource." How do I send the POST? Is it something I have to do via Curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FireFox add-on Poster must help.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/
Other similar tools:
[Are there Firefox extension (or any other browser) that allow to send arbitrary POST data to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725998/are-there-firefox-extension-or-any-other-browser-that-allow-to-send-arbitrary)

Comment: I found out I can use amazon sdk to do it but I ended up using cloudberry and bucketexplorer. Good to know that tool though, thanks!