# Why doesn't 'POST'ing parameters work on the FB login URL?

Tags: forms, http, authentication, post

I want to write a script that will log in to facebook.

I tried going to this URL:

https://www.facebook.com/login.php?&email=example@example.com&pass=password

but it doesnt work, it just redirects to the same page.

Comment: because facebook ignores them.  IIRC, you can specify the email address with post, but not the password.

Comment: In the google chrome "network" dev tool it says that both params are POSTed

Comment: Yeah.  oops.  my comment is mistaken: facebook ignores GET. IIRC, you can specify the email address with GET, but not the password.  (not POST)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is GET, not POST.

Generally sending a password in a GET query is not a good idea. It is visible as plain text in the browser, in your request, which may be sniffed with a sniffing tool and in your browser history. That's probably why Facebook does not accept it.

Comment: However, that does not mean that sniffing plaintext POST parameters is much more difficult than sniffing GET parameters (when not using https)

Comment: Write a little bit of html will do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307379/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-a-web-browser

Comment: Or use a firefox extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725998/are-there-firefox-extension-or-any-other-browser-that-allow-to-send-arbitrary